# In general, can I upgrade laptop's HDD with SSD?

Tags: laptop

I'm not sure if I can do that on my laptop. Will BIOS complain? Will there be overheating issues? I have SONY VAIO VPCEF44FX
Thanks.

Comment: Hi user1078719. I think this question is currently a bit too localised. However if you want to know if it is generally possible to replace a HDD with an SSD then the answer is almost always yes. And a SSD usually produces less heat.

Comment: You can *replace* your HDD with SSD, certainly. Not sure what you mean by upgrade. What do you want to know about the upgrade process? That would make it a more answerable question.

Comment: Upgrade means replace with a better version.

Comment: I don't think the question is too localized when it comes to replacing HDDs with SDDs, they are basically compatible. However, there are other issues to deal with in case you ghost a HDD to a SDD, which is already discussed in many other threads.